# Links between Langlands program, elliptic curves, and cryptography

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-curves, cryptography, langlands-program

There is a link between the Langlands program and elliptic curves as well as a link between elliptic curves and cryptography. I am wondering how a thing in the Langlands program can be translated to something interesting in cryptography?

For example, do the proof of [Langlands functoriality conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.0917) leads to a breakthrough result in cryptography? Or do functoriality for endoscopy pairs have been already used in cryptography? If yes, what are the intermediary products in the theory of elliptic curves?

I am relatively comfortable with the Langlands program and theory of elliptic curves individually (but don't know much about how one field interacts with the other). Any reference/clue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I never saw crytography when investigating L-functions, so if there is something it is well hidden. Now the L-functions tell a lot on what happens when choosing a random prime to do whatever calculation-algorithm which is quite common in cryptography. And Langlands is telling a lot on L-functions.

Comment: I don't know much about cryptography, but just curious whether Langlands program can be really used in this domain. My naive thinking tells me there must be something (at least some applications of the functoriality in arithmetic geometry), but I can't find out what it should be.

Answer (score 2):

Arithmetic geometry in general has applications to areas such as cryptography and physics. There is much research about the interplay between arithmetic geometry and the Langlands correspondence for number fields.

However, I am not aware of an immediate "breakthrough result" for cryptography following from the Langlands program.
I am sure that arithmetic geometry offers new techniques for cryptography, but I am no expert here. There was a [thematic semester](https://www.lebesgue.fr/content/sem2019) on *The correspondences between Geometry, Arithmetic and Cryptography*,
which has discussed also "the link between automorphic forms and Galois theory in the Langlands programme, and bridges between the world of error-correcting codes and cryptography."

Comment: Thank you very much ! I will look at this thematic semester.